Solr - read data from postgresql in batches
My team and I want to use solr for better text searching. The idea is solr fetches data periodically from postgresql. We managed to use dataimporter.last_index_time for taking only newest changes, and its working. But, we don't know how to modify data config to force solr to use pagination(like limit and offset) when reads data from postgresql. We think that if solr, on initial start, when tries to fetch whole table, with milions rows, postgresql will crash or become unusable.

Why would the database crash when fetching a couple of million records? This is standard work for databases. Besides that it’s the application that might run into trouble

We think that if sol ... postgresql will crash or become unusable. What did it do when you tested it? Besides with a couple million rows Postgres is just getting warmed up.

Try modifying your config xml file and add pagination logic. Also, you can use start and toe parameters.
